# Authenticate Node app to download captions via YouTube Data API

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-oauth

I'm writing a Node application to get captions for videos from a YouTube channel.

I've downloaded credentials, got the [YouTube Node quickstart sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs) working and successfully added code to get a list of captions for a single video ID:

```
 service.captions.list(parameters, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    for (const item of response.data.items) {
      console.log(item.id);
      // service.captions.download({id: item.id});
    }
  });
```

However, if I uncomment the line to download captions, I get a 'Login Required' error.

How do I log in, or run code to log in?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "I've downloaded credentials"? Can you post the code where you use those credentials to create the `service` object. Also, are you trying to access your own YouTube account, or is this for users to access their own accounts?

Comment: Hi @pinoyyid: I've downloaded the credentials (client_secret.json) as per the instructions in the quickstart linked to above. My code is the same as the quickstart sample, except that instead of calling service.channels.list(), I call service.captions.list() as in the code I've included above. I'm accessing a YouTube account for which I'm a channel manager (and I select this as expected from the authorisation UI when first running the sample.)

Comment: if you call `service,channels.list()` does that work? Have you confirmed that a Service Account has permission to access captions, ie "Note that the YouTube Data API supports the service account flow only for YouTube content owners that own and manage multiple YouTube channels. Specifically, content owners can use service accounts to call API methods that support the onBehalfOfContentOwner request parameter."

Comment: Hi @pinoyyid. Thanks for following up on this. service.channels.list() works fine. I've actually solved this separately — I'll write that up and post a link here.